# how can we broadcast live video from android with http

Tags: android

I have tried using libstreaming library and succeed to live stream using rtsp and played in vlc player but i am not able to use http for streaming so that i can broadcast my video streaming to my own server,Is there any way to do that ?

I have a requirement to broadcast live video from android app and that can also be viewed from another android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you getting it in a wrong way, you don't broadcast to server you send (upload) and server broadcast that for you. broadcasting is sending same data to all connected client at the same time. clients don't broadcast data for the server. also you can setup a http-server on your android but since you have a separate server already I don't think that would be what you want.

so if it's java with UDP case then start would be something like this:

```
UDPServer.java:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[FRAMESIZE];
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            // IP and port of the client who sent you this
            // in case of some type of feedback since UDP doesn't do that
            //InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            //int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            // store data somewhere sharable lock it before store it
        }
    }
}

UDPClient.java:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader inFromUser =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[FRAMESIZE];
        /* WebCam Frame Capture Code*/
        // but you should do it continuously on your frame capture event
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, PORT);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

here some references:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-datagramudp-client-example.html
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example
https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Android_UDP_Client

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

and by some modifications I think this is what you want :

[http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)/

Comment: My requirement is android will capture the live video and that will be send to server and server will again broadcast that live video to all the other devices, and the issue is to send live stream of the captured video to the server using http

Comment: What language are you in. are you in javascript? if so you can make a connection to your server using web socket and then send each frame on your final frame capture event . but if you are in java or c++ try to connect with UDP since they are much faster.

Comment: I am in java ,and i am android developer ,Can you give any reference how video stream can be transmitted using UDP?  ,and I dont have much knowledge on server side technologies,and how the server will work to broadcast that video stream on web.